# How to incorporate federated search results from box.net into Apache Solr

Tags: search, box-api

Looking at ways to incorporate search results from box accounts with my internal Apache Solr based search.

From what i can see, box.com does not provide ability to search and receive results according to the opensearch standard.

What is the recommended approach for incorporating results via federated search ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at SMEStorage.com. I know their on-premise or hosted Cloud Appliance can plug into Solr for federated deep search across different information sources, including Box.